# Can you tell a screenreader to ignore HTML tags on Android?

Tags: android, accessibility, xamarin.android, screen-readers

I have a TextView with some HTML content. If I turn on Accessibility and use TalkBack, it reads out the tags. E.g. "Less than, p, greater than, less than" etc. etc.

I have tried setting the ContentDescription to plainText (a variable contain plain text), but the reader seems to ignore it and use the Text property instead...

```
//Dynamically set accessibility text for screen readers
textView.ContentDescription = plainText;
```

Answer (score 0):

To read the plain text version of the HTML, you will need to create a custom view with the Accessibility API methods overridden.  There is pretty good documentation here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/accessibility/apps.html

However, reading "less than" and "greater than" is the correct behaviour -- if you are displaying HTML to sighted users the screenreader should give access to the same information.